# C# Does not Recognize InputSystem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, error-handling

When i opened my Project, i suddenly got a bunch of Errors in the log, i was able to fix most of them, but the errors for the InputSystem are saying that it's not recognized. i Have the InputSystem installed, The Input is set to Both new and old, and i already tried regenerating the project files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmUPi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e1A3.png)

Comment: Unfortunately i did not find a fix to it,
But what i did was use an Old version of my project and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

On 2021.3.7 I installed the new Input system from the package manager, hit yes when it asks to restart the editor, came back in and it recognizes it. Try to revert all the settings you've done so far and do the same process. I've had my fair share of times it didn't recognize it too, it's clunky for sure.

Comment: I tried this, and it looked like the problem was solved, but then when the shaders recompiled the same errors appeared shortly after